# How to have a conversation with a botpress bot using HTTP requests and responses?

Tags: postman, httprequest, botpress

Want to know how to have a conversation with a botpress bot using HTTP requests and responses (want to eventually send these requests through Postman). I am able to have admin access to this bot. Also, Currently looking at here: https://botpress.com/docs/api-documentation/ but it seems unclear. Therefore, was wondering if you guys could please provide some assistance with this?

Comment: You provide minimal, reproducible code and a question about a specific, non-trivial issue in that code. We provide a specific answer to that specific question. The page you link seems pretty clear. Aside from that, you'll also need to study REST and web authentication. Both topics have plenty of resources on the web to help you learn.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like as of now this is not possible according to: https://discord.com/channels/1108396290624213082/1162371490864431186. Also, here is another post about this: https://discord.com/channels/1108396290624213082/1167099547143655514.